# Changing the background color of a ListBoxItem

Tags: c#, windows-8, listboxitem, windows-store-apps

I'm writing a Windows Store app in C#, how would one go about changing the background color of a ListBoxItem?

Comment: ListBoxItem.Background = Brushes.White; not working though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  You need to modify the ItemTemplate for the ListBox. Right-click the ListBox, select Edit Additional Templates -> ItemTemplate.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example for you, you should carry out more research before asking small questions with out providing code but i hope this helps [Check this example out](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8134/Coloring-items-in-a-ListBox)

Comment: in fact that I have tried most of the similar questions Stack Overflow has to offer, none of them work, including the link you provide